# Resolving interface with generic type in ServiceStack Request filter

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control

My question is - is it possible and if it is - how, to resolve interface in ServiceStack request filter that uses generic type and the type is retrieved dynamically from **DTO** of request. The idea is that I have multiple validators defined in my assembly and they use interface that has a generic type. Example:

`AddressSaveValidator : BaseValidator<AddressSaveRequest>;`

My goal is to on request resolve and see if request has a validator that is defined for such request, then validate and then log the results. The only problem is that I don't know how to resolve interface with generic type. This is example of how would I use it:

```
        RequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto)  =>
        {
            var validator = container.Resolve<IValidator<typeof(dto)>>();
            var  validatorResult = validator.Validate(dto);
            if(validatorResult.IsValid)
            {
                var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
                var result = logger.LogValidationResults(validationResult);
                throw ValidationException(result);
            }
        });
```

Of course, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the `IValidator` for a request with `ValidatorCache.GetValidator()` but you can't throw an Exception in GlobalRequestFilters you'll need to write the Error directly to the response, e.g:

```
var validator = ValidatorCache.GetValidator(req, dto.GetType());
using (validator as IDisposable)
{
    var validatorResult = validator.Validate(dto);
    if (validatorResult.IsValid) return;

    var errorResponse = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(dto, validatorResult.ToErrorResult());

    res.WriteToResponse(req, errorResponse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the ValidatorCache feature in ServiceStack. I could not find documentation about it. How is it filled? Automatically?  Would be very grateful if you could provide insight in using it.

Comment: It's automatically populated when [Validation Features are registered](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#validation-feature), the example in answer shows how you can use it.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to get validator from ValidatorCache I get null even though I did the necessary steps:  
1)**Defined validator**  
public class TestValidator : BaseValidator<ValidationTestRequest> { .... }  
2)    **Registered validators**  
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AppHost).Assembly);  
3) **Added Validation Feature**  
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

Comment: @ViestursGribulis Note: you need to inherit from ServiceStack's built-in `AbstractValidator<T>`, see the [Validation Example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#fluentvalidation-for-request-dtos)

Comment: I have BaseValidator<T> that historically inherits from FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<T> but not SeviceStack.FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<T>. Could this cause ValidatorCache not to fill up with Validators?

Comment: @ViestursGribulis yes, it needs to inherit from ServiceStack's implementation.

Comment: I see, so I need to rewrite whole legacy code to enable validation via ServiceStack filters. Is there anything I can do other than that?

Comment: You need to use ServiceStack's implementation in order to use ServiceStack's features.